# Error when registering a SAPUI5 app in Fiori Launchpad from Web IDE

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I have deployed a basic UI5 app in the SCP subaccount correctly. I created this app from a SAPUI5 Fiori template.

Then, when I try to register it in SAP Fiori Launchpad, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I check in the code but I do not have any instruction using `length`. If you see the console in Web IDE, I have no errors:

[image: Console log - WebIDE]

Here I attach an image with the template I use to create my app.

[image: Image of Fiori Template used to create my app]

If it helps, I will attach the code in the view and controller. If more code it is necessary, please let me know.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("fichajes.fichajes.controller.homePage", {
    onInit: function() {
      var userModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/services/userapi/currentUser");
      this.getView().setModel(userModel, "userapi");
    }
  });
});
```

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="fichajes.fichajes.controller.homePage"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
  xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar"
>
  <semantic:FullscreenPage id="page"
    navButtonPress=".onNavBack"
    showNavButton="true"
    title="Usuario: {userapi>/name}"
  >
    <semantic:content>
      <ObjectHeader id="objectheader1Object"
        intro=""
        title="{userapi>/name}"
        icon="http://www.megadatosgratis.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/consejos-para-ser-empleado-eficiente.jpg"
        numberState="None"
        backgroundDesign="Transparent"
        condensed="false"
      >
        <attributes>
          <ObjectAttribute id="objectattribute1Object"
            title="Importe máximo para flexibilizar"
            text="{userapi>/name}"
            active="false"
          />
          <ObjectAttribute id="objectattribute2Object"
            title="Importe destinado al plan flex"
            text="{userapi>/firstName}"
            active="false"
          />
          <ObjectAttribute id="objectattribute3Object"
            title="Importe disponible para flexibilizar"
            text="{userapi>/lastName}"
            active="false"
          />
        </attributes>
      </ObjectHeader>
    </semantic:content>
  </semantic:FullscreenPage>
</mvc:View>
```

I have attached the error with the F12 tool. Is the only way I have found to search the error. In the console of the Web IDE there is no error shown when I try to register the app in SAP Fiori Launchpad. I have checked all files in the project and there is no `length` used anywhere.

[image: Browser Console Error]

---

I had found the line of code in the browser console where the error occurs.

```
 a.application.componentUrl = c, a.application.navigationComponentName = s, a.application.html5ApplicationName = e.hcpAppName, a.application.HCPParentApplicationName = u, 1 !== e.selectedGroups.length ||
```

At the end you can see the e.selectedGroups.length. Here is the error. I do not know how to fix the Core-preload file.

Comment: The error is obviously not in the supplied code-snippets since I can't find any `.length` here - can you supply the line and file where the error occurs?

Comment: I Edit the question with new information in the browser console. In the Web IDE I have not found 'lenght' used anywhere nor error log when trying to register in SAP Fiori Launchpad.

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong. I search for 'length'.

Comment: In your error message it says:
“… encountered unknown setting ‘data’ for class ‘sap.ui.core.ListItem’ …“

Are you using ListItem somewhere in your coding ?